# Amazon Red Shift: How to write query batches similar to Stored Procedures in SQL Server

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

We are trying to port a SQL Server based application to Amazon Redshift. Redshift looks promising in terms of performance and Scalability. We are facing issues finding replacement for Stored Procedures to execute queries in batches.

Thanks

Comment: please explain what you have tried for better solution for your question..

Comment: Hi, We have created a database cluster on redshift and we are able to run queries on the Database. But we are not able to run query batches similar to what Stored Proceedures help in SQL Server. Need help on running batches.

Comment: Stored Procedures are now supported in Amazon Redshift from version 1.0.7287 (late April 2019). Please review the document ["Creating Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html) for more information on getting started with stored procedures.

Answer (score 4):

Update: Stored Procedures are now supported in Amazon Redshift from version 1.0.7287 (late April 2019). Please review the document ["Creating Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html) for more information on getting started with stored procedures.

---

No neat replacement exists, sadly.

As I see it, you have a few choices:

1. Shell/CMD scripts that call `psql` that you run from as schedule jobs.
2. An ETL tool (SSIS). Bear in mind it'll mostly be running shell/cmd scripts.
3. SQL Server stored procs that use xp_cmdshell to call `psql`.
4. Use AWS Data Pipeline to run your batch processing.

Comment: We currently use Azkaban for this purpose. It's nice because steps run in parallel where possible and it's relatively easy for analysts (e.g. not programmers) to create workflows.

Comment: Stored Procedures are now supported in Amazon Redshift from version 1.0.7287 (late April 2019). Please review the document ["Creating Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html) for more information on getting started with stored procedures.